# StackExchange.Redis: Get the count of channel subscriptions (i.e. PUBSUB NUMSUB)

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

is there a way to get the number of channel subscriptions to a specific Redis channel through the StackExchange.Redis library? When interacting with Redis directly, it would work with the PUBSUB NUMSUB command (http://redis.io/commands/pubsub) but I don't see an equivalent call in the C# client library.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a *server* command (as opposed to a *database* command), so the [same guidance applies as for `KEYS`, `SCAN`, `FLUSHDB`, etc](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysScan). Short version: use `GetServer()`. Longer version: read the linked article above.

The `PUBSUB` methods are:

- `PUBSUB CHANNELS`: `server.SubscriptionChannels[Async](...)`
- `PUBSUB NUMPAT`: `server.SubscriptionPatternCount[Async](...)`
- `PUBSUB NUMSUB`: `server.SubscriptionSubscriberCount[Async](...)`

Comment: Is there is way to do this in Golang?

Comment: @ShyamShinde sure - this is ultimately a server feature; at least [one of the golang redis libraries](https://redis.io/clients#go) should support it... and if not: you could add a PR!

Comment: Any updates on this issue ? Is there any way to get the count of subscribers for a given channel using StackExchangeRedis ?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian um ... no update is necessary, since the code in the answer above continues to work; use `GetServer()`, and any of the 3 methods shown above, depending on what you're trying to ask the server

Comment: I was hoping the methods above could help but i am looking to solve the following scenario:
For a given `ISubscriber` instance , is there a way to remove all delegates that have been added ? (Even more fine-grained : for a specific channel) ?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian firstly, `ISubscriber` is only a gateway; the state is at the connection/multiplexer level, so "per `ISubscriber` instance" : not a thing. To remove all delegates: there is an unsubscribe method that takes a channel; if you don't include a handler, it does everything on that channel

Comment: Yea i am facing a issue where although i match every `Subscribe(targetHandler)` with a corresponding `Unsubscribe(targetHandler) ` at the end of the ISubscriber lifecycle on a specific channel , when creating new `ISubscriber`(s) they get messages multiple times ; which makes me believe that somehow a specific `handler` was not disposed and is still roaming around listening to messages.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian again: ISubscriber is only a gateway to the muxer; calls to GetSubscriber are not independent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226286/discussion-between-bercovici-adrian-and-marc-gravell).